# Company/Organization image not showing

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, developer-story

When I edit my developer story and select company, it shows the company image

[image]

But just after the save it disappears
[image]

Comment: @Daniel A. White, Still waiting for any response..

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the late response. We haven't had a team working on the developer story feature for a while.

When we created this feature, we backfilled companies and logos from Crunchbase. We currently do not have any mechanism for keeping logos up to date with Crunchbase, which is the reason why the old logo was wasn't saving.

I manually updated the logo, so this should be reflected on your developer story now.

Comment: I've also noted there's no way to edit the current image or company URL. I've set some in my DevStory and I'd like to update the info but there's no way to do it. A shame...

Comment: @Metafaniel we're in discussions about how we can replace this feature with more robust company pages. For now, you can edit the Name/Url/Image of an existing job story item by pressing the x button in the company input box.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I understand the feature will be upgraded in the future that'd be great, yet to clarify speaking of current behavior, you were right! Clicking the `X` button in the name of the company enables the edition of the URL field and the image. This is counter intuitive as it seems to be the control is just to edit the company name. Thanks!